# Change css inside function call not working

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change css inside function call.ie, in my case add style to check box when function return true. But it is not working.

Script code ,

```
function checkAll()
{
    if ( document.myForm.myCB.length )
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < document.myForm.myCB.length; x++)
            {
                var flag=1;
                    if (flag == 1)
                    {
                        document.myForm.myCB[x].checked = true; 
                $('.checkbox').attr("style", "background-position:top left;");              
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        document.myForm.myCB[x].checked = false;
                    }

            }
        }

}
```

Html code is,

```
   <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="" method="get"> 

   <p><input type="button" name="ca_v1_on" value="Check All" onclick="checkAll(1);"/></p>
   <p> <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="yes" id="myCB"/></p>

  <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="yes" id="myCB"/></p>

  <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="yes" id="myCB"/></p>
 </form>
```

please help.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

use [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for jQuery:

```
$('.checkbox').css("background-position", "top left");
```

or simple javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
     elements[i].backgroundPosition = 'top left';
}
```

Note that `getElementsByClassName()` is [not available up to and including IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements).

You can get it working on all browsers, [check this](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/) for some comparisions an good alternatives like:

```
if (!('getElementsByClassName' in document)) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className, parentElement) {
        if (Prototype.BrowserFeatures.XPath) {
            var q = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + className + " ')]";
            return document._getElementsByXPath(q, parentElement);
        } else {
            var children = ($(parentElement) || document.body).getElementsByTagName('*');
            var elements = [],
                child;
            for (var i = 0, length = children.length; i < length; i++) {
                child = children[i];
                if (Element.hasClassName(child, className)) elements.push(Element.extend(child));
            }
            return elements;
        }
    };
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

See this line:

```
$('.checkbox').attr("style", "background-position:top left;");
```

You could write it in this way :

```
$('.checkbox').css("background-position", "top left");
```

Answer (score 0):

to change css you should use the .css and not the .attr

so  this

`$('.checkbox').attr("style", "background-position:top left;");`

will make

`$('.checkbox').css("background-position", "top left");`

sported in all browsers with JavaScript if you want to make it different for browsers with out JavaScript take a look at [modernizr](http://modernizr.com)